# How to list WP multisite languages

Tags: multisite, plugin-wpml

how to get the array list of multi-site with multi languages, for e.g i am on `site 1` and want to know about other sites languages `site 2`, `site 3`.

Site Structure is:

```
EG (Egypt - with 2 languages)
------------------------
    EN | AR
------------------------
PK (Pakistan - Single language)
    EN
------------------------
LK (Srilanka - Single language)
    EN
```

i can get the sites with `get_sites()` but i need to 2 dimensional array containing country code as parent and child contains available languages.

Comment: edit your question to add which plugin you use for languages management

Comment: @mmm i've already added the tag `plugin-wpml` does it need to add in question too ?

Answer (score 1):

Fix it by querying to wpml languages table.

1. get all sites
2. loop through the `sites` get `blog ids`.
3. Query ICL languages table of each blog(each multi-site)
4. Add into `Array` & play accordingly

> **`$blog_id == 1`** condition used because the base site doesn't have blog id prefix with table name

Here is the function

```
function getSitesLanguages() {
    $blog_languages = array();
    global $wpdb;
    $sites = get_sites();
    foreach ( $sites as $key => $site ) {
        $blog_languages[ $site->blog_id ] = '';
        $blog_id                           = $site->blog_id . '_';
        if ( $blog_id == 1 ) {
            $blog_id = '';
        }
        $QUERY  = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT code FROM ' . $wpdb->base_prefix . $blog_id . 'icl_languages WHERE active =  %d', 1 ).PHP_EOL;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results( $QUERY );
        if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
            foreach ( $result as $key2 => $langObj ) {
                $blog_languages[ $site->blog_id ][] = $langObj->code;
            }
        }
    }

    return $blog_languages;
}
```